# How can I make a valid SQL command out of this GUI?

Tags: sql, powershell, automation

I am trying to make a support ticket program that can make changes to a current ticket by running `UPDATE` commands on the Database.
The GUI looks like this:

[image: GUI]

With this GUI, a supporter can edit the desired fields of the support ticket. My problem is that
**the supporter must be able to leave a text field empty to not change that information.**

What I have now is:

```
$id = $textBox1.text
$supporter = $textBox2.text
$description = $textBox3.text

if ($radioButton1.Checked)
{
    $status = 1
}elseif ($radioButton2.Checked)
{
    $status = 0
}else
{
    #don't change anything with status
}

$sqlcommand = "
UPDATE [tickettable]
SET supporter = $supporter, description = $description, status = $status
WHERE ID = $id
"
```

With my code, the supporter has to enter all information again, even if he only wants to change the description for example. Is there any way how to make an automated SQL command?

> please note: I know that some code is missing, but that's because it's
>   not important for the question.

Comment: I think you have to write 3 separate updates, using case/if to determine which ones to use.

side note: make sure the radiobutton names are what you think they are. I'd imagine 1 would be close but your logic seems to think the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. It's not a direct answer to my question, **but it's a different** (maybe even better) **approach**. 
I made a new button next to the "ID" field with the name "load" which writes the current values for the fields into the input fields (since the information is already given in the database)

Now, my program acts like this:

After entering the `ID` and clicking on "load", the program reads the current information on the DB and writes it into the input fields. That way, the SQL command is **always the same** (since we can update all fields) and on the PowerShell side, **I don't need to write 100 if/else statements.**

[image: GUI image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to create multiple if else statements, if you don't want to spend weeks. :) Note that **I have not covered all the possible combinations!** This is just an example how you could do it. You just have to cover all the cases.

```
$id = $textBox1.text
$supporter = $textBox2.text
$description = $textBox3.text

if ($radioButton1.Checked)
{
    $status = 1
}elseif ($radioButton2.Checked)
{
    $status = 0
}else
{
    #don't change anything with the status
}
if ($supporter != "" -and $description != "" -and $status != ""){
     $setcommand = "SET supporter = $supporter, description = $description" status = $status
}
elseif ($supporter == "" -and $description != "" -and $status != ""){
     $setcommand = "SET description = $description, status = $status"
}
elseif ($supporter == "" -and $description != "" -and $status == ""){
     $setcommand = "SET description = $description"
}
elseif ($supporter == "" -and $description == "" -and $status == ""){
     Write-Host "Nothing to do"
}

$sqlcommand = "
UPDATE [tickettable]
$setcommand
WHERE ID = $id
"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use something like this

```
$sqlcommand = "
UPDATE [tickettable]
WHEN $supporter IS NOT NULL
THEN SET supporter = $supporter
WHEN $description IS NOT NULL sdf
THEN description = $description
WHEN $status IS NOT NULL 
THEN SET status = $status
WHERE ID = $id
"
```